# How to dynamically load large JSON files in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, google-chrome, getjson

I'm trying to figure out what the best way is to dynamically load a series of language dictionary files (English, French, etc.) into a Chrome extension. The constraints I'm dealing with:

1. I'm running a content script that controls browser actions based on a gesture recognition device (the LEAP), so it's always running in the active tab.
2. The user can select a different language by using a series of gestures to open a menu page and picking a new language.
3. Each dictionary file is pretty big (~5MB) and there are a lot of them (25+), so I can't load them all when the extension initializes or it really clogs things up.
4. I want to host the dictionary files in the extension's home directory; rather than hosted somewhere externally.
5. I can store the user's language choice in Chrome/storage, but as far as I understand, the JSON dictionaries are too big to put in there.

To summarize, I want to be able to dynamically load a locally hosted, fairly large JSON array (~5MB) into a Chrome content script based on a user action.  What's the best way to do this without running into Access-Control-Allow-Origin issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your JSON filename to the manifest: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources

This way you can access the JSON file inside the extension from any content script.

You can also load the file in the background page (it is better), and send a message from the content script to the background page to fetch specific data from the JSON. This is better, because your load the JSON once, for all your tabs.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Extra thanks for the note loading the chosen file into the background script; should improve performance even more.